# How to process a value form a dropdown form item in PHP

Tags: php, forms, selection

I have the following issue regarding PHP. First off, I barely know some aspects of PHP, so excuse the newb question.

I'm working on a thing that outputs a little snippet of code so a friend of mine can update his website without coming to me for help. Depending on the situation he could have different option for this, options that output different snippets. I create a selection form(dropdown) and the values for each is like this: **$option1**, **$option2** & **$option3**. Then I made something like **$example = $_REQUEST['selectionform'];** that catches the value selected. My problem is that when I echo **$example** I get only **"$option1"** as text, and **$option1** does not get processed as it would have if I'd echo it directly. I really hope that you understand what I'm saying, I have no idea about PHP syntax and terminology.

Do you have any idea how to get the option selected in the form to get processed as if I would echo that value directly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not echoing the value through php, you're explicitly placing it within the page. Assuming $optionN are variabels you have in PHP, try the following:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="<?php echo $option1; ?>">option 1</option>
  <option value="<?php echo $option2; ?>">option 1</option>
  <option value="<?php echo $option3; ?>">option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could be echoing the variable like this:

```
echo '$option1';
```

Which wouldn't output the string while in single quotes. Try:

```
echo "$option1";
```

or

```
echo $option1;
```

Remember also to echo inside of PHP tags.